# How get query result with elastic4s like in Kibana

Tags: scala, elastic4s

I'm trying to extract an individu from the ElasticSearch with Elastic4s.
I'm using ES 5.5.1 and I connect to it with http client. I would like use an ES query like a Kibana Get Search

the Kibana query :

```
GET /crm/profiles/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "_id": [
        "40105"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

the begining of my code :

```
var customerId = "0231545"
var esQuery = """{"query":{"terms":{"_id":["""" + customerId + """"]}}}"""
val client = HttpClient(ElasticsearchClientUri(esHosts, 9200))
```

I find a lot of post on this topic but anyone works or corresponds to my problem. One idea could be :

```
val resu = client.execute {
  search("crm/profiles").matchQuery("_id", customerId)
}
```

But it doesn't work and there is no error, resu is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a match query here, as a match query will run the query through the analyzer. In your kibana query you used a term query and so you can use the same here.

```
val resu = client.execute {
  search("crm/profiles").termQuery("_id", customerId)
}
```